# Are NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods fired with iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, icloud

I'm using iCloud and Core Data. I have a table view which uses a fetched results controller. If I manually delete a row, my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are called (for example `–controllerDidChangeContent:`). If the change comes through iCloud, the delegate methods aren't called.

Is this normal behavior? Could something else in my code be preventing these methods from being called? Should an iCloud driven change cause the delegate methods to fire?

Answer (score 0):

Both `iCloud` and `NSFetchedResultsController` deal with the `NSManagedObjectContext` being used.

A few things to check:

1. Is your iCloud content being merged in to the managed object context?
2. Are you using a different managed object context for iCloud than your fetched results controller?